# What are relics and what do they do?

Tags: hero-siege

After killing the first boss i have looted my first "Relic", but i can't figure out what's it effect. It appears on my menu, but there's no "hover" tooltip or something.

[image: Fire Dagger or something]

Answer (score 2):

> **Relics are items that will help improve your game-play in some way. They are the games take on upgrades.**

There are four kinds of relics:

> **1.** Weapon Enhancements: These are Relics that give your weapons extra powers.
>
> **2.** Passive: These are Relics that improve your characters skills.
>
> **3.** Active: These are Relics that need activation, therefore you can only hold one. After usage the Relic will have a cooldown before it can be used again.
>
> **4.** Orbiting: These are Relics that are visible in game, and will float around you. They will help during the fight, damaging enemies or protecting you from hits.

Your relic is a passive relic, called the `golden dagger`, and gives +40 Swiftness.

[Source](http://herosiege.wikia.com/wiki/Relics)